# Wordpress API: Add / Remove Tags on Posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I know it seems like a simple operation, but I can't find any resource or documentation that explains how to programmatically add and remove tags to a post using the post ID.

Below is a sample of what I'm using, but it seems to overwrite all the other tags...

```
function addTerm($id, $tax, $term) {

    $term_id = is_term($term);
    $term_id = intval($term_id);
    if (!$term_id) {
        $term_id = wp_insert_term($term, $tax);
        $term_id = $term_id['term_id'];
        $term_id = intval($term_id);
    }
    $result =  wp_set_object_terms($id, array($term_id), $tax, FALSE);

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first call [get_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) to get all the terms that exist already.

**Updated code**

```
function addTerm($id, $tax, $term) {

    $term_id = is_term($term);
    $term_id = intval($term_id);
    if (!$term_id) {
        $term_id = wp_insert_term($term, $tax);
        $term_id = $term_id['term_id'];
        $term_id = intval($term_id);
    }

    // get the list of terms already on this object:
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms($id, $tax)
    $terms[] = $term_id;

    $result =  wp_set_object_terms($id, $terms, $tax, FALSE);

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: FYI: is_term has been changed to term_exists

Comment: Where is the "remove tag" part of this?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `wp_add_post_tags($post_id,$tags)`;

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it:

```
$tag="This is the tag"
$PostId=1; //
wp_set_object_terms( $PostId, array($tag), 'post_tag', true );
```

*Note: `wp_set_object_terms()` expects the second parameter to be an array.*

Answer (score 2):

Since WordPress 3.6 there is `wp_remove_object_terms( $object_id, $terms, $taxonomy )` that does exactly that.

The `$terms` parameter represents the `slug(s)` or `ID(s)` of the `term(s)` to remove and accepts array, int or string.

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remove_object_terms

Answer (score 1):

> What if you dont know the post id? You just want to add the tag to all new posts created?

When using the WordPress API function `add_action('publish_post', 'your_wp_function');`, the function you are calling automatically gets the `post_id` injected as the first argument:

```
function your_wp_function($postid) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, [wp_set_object_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) can handle everything you need by itself:

If you really need a separate function:

```
function addTag($post_id, $term, $tax='post_tag') {
    return wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $term, $tax, TRUE);
}
```

`wp_set_object_terms`'s parameters:

1. the Post ID
2. Accepts...

   - a single string (e.g. 'Awesome Posts')
   - a single ID of an existing tag (e.g. 1), or
   - an array of either (e.g. array('Awesome Posts',1)).
   - **NOTE:** If you provide a NON-ID, it *will* create the tag automatically.
3. The taxonomy (e.g. for default tags, use 'post_tag').
4. Whether to...

   - (`FALSE`) REPLACE ALL existing terms with the ones provided, or
   - (`TRUE_`) APPEND/ADD to the existing terms.

Happy coding!