# Wordpress - Delete all tags by Post ID

Tags: wordpress, tags

I've got a function to add a tag by post ID, but now I would like to delete all the current tags for that ID before adding my new tags?

Does anyone know a built in function or wordpress query to do this?

-Hudson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can access the database directly (PhpMyAdmin), the quickest way is a SQL request.

Look at the [database schema](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) in the codex :

```
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships
WHERE wp_term_relationships.object_id = 'yourPostId'
AND wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'post_tag';
```

**WARNING :** obviously, modifying directly the database is dangerous. Be careful doing that.

Comment: I believe this might also delete category associations.

Comment: Yes it does. To delete only tags, this code must be precised (by a condition on wp_term_taxonomy but since I haven't a database, I can't say what condition right now :/)

Comment: I looked at a WP database and edited my response. The new SQL request  only delete the post tags.

Comment: The wp_term_taxonomy table used in the where-clause isn't joined, so the deletion will fail. The following will work and so it's even more dangerous ;-)
DELETE FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id = 'yourPostId' AND term_taxonomy_id IN (SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_taxonomy WHERE taxonomy = 'post_tag')

Answer (score 1):

Should help you get there:

[Wordpress API: Add / Remove Tags on Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2436487/wordpress-api-add-remove-tags-on-posts)

I found this function: [wp_delete_term](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_term) See if it helps you...

Comment: I found that one, and thats where I got my add tags script, but I do not read or understand a delete all tags function in that resource.

Answer (score 0):

I pieced this together. Its pure database work, because I believe there is no quick function to delete a tag via ID, (but I am still not 100% certain).

```
//define array of tags
$tags = array("new tag","new tag 2");     
//define post ID
$val = 254;

 //delete tags associated to post id
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table_prefix."term_relationships tr JOIN ".$table_prefix."term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id=tt.term_taxonomy_id WHERE tr.object_id='$val' AND tt.taxonomy='post_tag'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result){echo $query; echo mysql_error();}

while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
        $tid = $arr['term_taxonomy_id'];
        $query2 = "DELETE FROM ".$table_prefix."term_relationships WHERE term_taxonomy_id='$tid'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
        if (!$result2){echo $query2; echo mysql_error();}
}


//add tags to post id           
wp_add_post_tags($val,$tags);
```