# How to change/delete tags in wordpress post with python XML-RPC API

Tags: python, wordpress, tags

Some wordpress themes use tags (for example 'featured') to show featured content on front page.

I have a python script that tags all posts with 'featured' tag, if certain custom_field value in a post is above defined value. That script also reduces these values each time it runs. Now, I would like to delete 'featured' tag from a post if this custom_field is below defined value.

to add tags for existing post I use:

```
server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(wp_url)
client = Client(wp_url, wp_username, wp_password)

post = client.call(posts.GetPost(postID))  
post.custom_fields = [{'id': featuredscoreID, 'key':'featuredscore','value': featscore}]
post.terms_names = {
    'post_tag': ['new tag'],
    }
post.call(posts.EditPost(postID, fpost))
```

but this code will only append tags.

```
print post.terms
```

will give me something like this:

```
[<WordPressTerm: Architecture>, <WordPressTerm: featured>, <WordPressTerm: Image>, <WordPressTerm: redevelopment>, <WordPressTerm: station>]
```

but I have found no way to replace or delete tags from existing post wordpress with python

something like: remove_tag(postID, 'tag')

thanks

**EDIT:**

It seems that it is not possible to delete tags(or tag) from post defined by post id ID using python XML-RPC API. It should be possible using database queries ([Wordpress - Delete all tags by Post ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356380/wordpress-delete-all-tags-by-post-id?rq=1)) but this certain example did not work (for me) and if there is need to run this (script) from some other location than localhost, one would need to loosen MySQL security and open some ports.

So, as solution, delete tag from wordpress and then apply it back to posts where it should be. To remove tags:

```
postTags = client.call(taxonomies.GetTerms('post_tag'))   

for tag in postTags:
    try:  
        if str(tag) == 'tag you would like to delete':
            client.call(taxonomies.DeleteTerm('post_tag', tag.id))         
    except:
        print "error"
```

automatic "featured" posts: http://imageoftheday.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to add code / plugins to your wordpress instance, then you can use [custom XML-RPC methods](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Extending) to handle this.

In Wordpress, you'll need to add a function that handles the magic on the server side. (I've added this to `functions.php` but better WP developers may know a better place for it. Perhaps a plugin.)

I believe you need [`wp_remove_object_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remove_object_terms) for your question, but of course your custom xml-rpc function can do whatever you like. I used this approach to delete custom fields, and to interact with another plugin I have installed.

```
function xmlrpc_add_method_delete_tags( $methods ) {
  $methods['my_namespace.delete_tags'] = 'xmlrpc_delete_tags_handler';
  return $methods;
}
add_filter('xmlrpc_methods', 'xmlrpc_add_method_delete_tags');

function xmlrpc_delete_tags_handler( $args ) {
  $result = array("ok" => false);

  try {
    // inspect $args for your parameters. I like to validate with regex,
    // but they should just be at the end of $args
    $n = count($args);
    $postId   = $args[$n-3];
    $term     = $args[$n-2];
    $taxonomy = $args[$n-1];

    $del = wp_remove_object_terms( $postId, $term, $taxonomy );
    $result["ok"] = ($del === true);

    if(is_wp_error($del)) {
      $result['wp_errors'] = $del->get_error_messages();
    }
  }
  catch(Exception $ex) {
    $result["msg"] = $ex->getMessage();
  }

  return json_encode($result); // send a json response
}
```

In Python, define a [`wordpress_xmlrpc.AuthenticatedMethod`](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/custom-methods.html#authenticated-methods) (or AnonymousMethod if you don't need authentication).

```
import json
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, AuthenticatedMethod

client = Client(WP_XMLRPC_URL, WP_USER, WP_PASSWORD)

class WordpressRemoveTag(AuthenticatedMethod):
    # method_name must match the key string you added to $methods in WP
    method_name = 'my_namespace.delete_tags'
    method_args = ('postId', 'term', 'taxonomy')

def remove_tag_from_obj(obj_id, term, tax='post_tag'):
    # return parsed json server response
    res = client.call(WordpressRemoveTag(obj_id, term, tax))
    return json.loads(res)
```

Then call `remove_tag_from_obj(...)` in python and you should get a json response from the server:

```
print remove_tag_from_obj(post.id, 'my_tag')
>> {"ok":true}
```